# Printing the elements of an array using call by reference

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference

The purpose of show() is just to display the elements of the array. What's wrong with my code? My understanding is that we pass the address of individual elements as parameters to display() which then passes the address of "x"(which stores the address of the elements) to show(). Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void disp(int *);
void show(int *);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int marks[] = {55,65,89,78,74,77,45};
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++)
    {
        disp(&marks[i]);
        printf("%d \n", (&marks[i]));
    }


        return 0;
}
void disp(int *x)
{
    show(&x);

}

void show(int *n)
{  printf("%d\n", *(*n));


}
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems, are you sure you know, what are you trying to do? start here -> `disp(&marks[i]);` and your function looks like this `void disp(int *x)`. And this is so wrong `printf("%d\n", *(*n));` Do you see why?

Comment: It's pretty close, actually. Just get rid of two `&`s and one `*`.

Comment: Can you please explain? I'm new to all of this.

Comment: @ManobhavPandey Are you trying to print The addresses to?? If so, you need the right sprecifier for printf function which is `&p` and you need to cast to void*. [Try this](https://ideone.com/IKfKhW).

Comment: `void show(int *);` and `void disp(int *x)
{
    show(&x); ...` will give a warning if your compiler has all warnings enable.  Enable them all and save time.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `show(&x)` in `disp()`, you're passing in a pointer to a pointer to an int (since `x` is a pointer to an int), even though `show()` only accepts a pointer to an int.

You should change the argument in `show()` from `int *n` to `int **n` to fix this issue.

Comment: No, `show(int*)` is fine. Just change the call to `show(x)` and fix that `*(*n)`.

Comment: Sure, there's more than one way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Well you almost got it right. Your `disp` function expects an address, so when you call `show` inside of it you shouldn't use the ampersand, because it's already an address. Then on the function `show`, you should use just `*n` instead of `*(*n)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is easier like what are you trying there:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ArrSIZE 7

void disp(int *);
void show(int *);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int marks[] = {55,65,89,78,74,77,45};

    for( i=0 ; i < ArrSIZE ; i++ )
    {
        disp(&marks[i]);
        printf("%p\n", (void*)&marks[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void disp(int *x)
{
    show(x);

}

void show(int *n)
{
    printf("%d\n", *n);
}
```

But, if you insist to do it in that way, then this is what you should do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ArrSIZE 7

void disp(int *);
void show(int **);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int marks[] = {55,65,89,78,74,77,45};

    for( i=0 ; i < ArrSIZE ; i++ )
    {
        disp(&marks[i]);
        printf("%p\n", (void*)&marks[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void disp(int *x)
{
    show(&x);

}

void show(int **n)
{
    printf("%d\n", **n);
}
```

Inside of `void show(int **n)` you need a pointer-to-pointer to work and remove those parentheses around `n`.

Like I said in my comment, if you need to print the address also you need the right specifier for that, which is `%p` and cast it to (void*).

Anyway both will Output this:

> ```
> 55
> 0xffefffec0
> 65
> 0xffefffec4
> 89
> 0xffefffec8
> 78
> 0xffefffecc
> 74
> 0xffefffed0
> 77
> 0xffefffed4
> 45
> 0xffefffed8
> ```

Comment: Thanks Michi! That really helped. Pointers are a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly do not use magic numbers. They are usually a source of numerous bugs. It is better to write

```
size_t i;
int marks[] = { 55, 65, 89, 78, 74, 77, 45 };
const size_t N = sizeof( marks ) / sizeof( *marks );

for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    //...
```

In this statement

```
printf("%d \n", (&marks[i]));
```

you are trying to output a pointer (if you indeed want to output the pointer) as an object of the type int that results in undefined behavior.

There must be

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )&marks[i] );
```

> My understanding is that we pass the address of individual elements as
>   parameters to display() which then passes the address of "x"(which
>   stores the address of the elements) to show().

In this case the function `show` should be declared like

```
void show(int **);
              ^^^
```

and defined like

```
void show( int **n )
{  
    printf( "%d\n", **n );
}
```